# How should I suppose to print $headcount alone in the following statement? Suggest any pre-defined functuions too

Tags: php, for-loop, while-loop

I flip a coin until I get three heads in a row!

```
<?php 

$headcount = 0;
$flipcount  = 0;

while ($headcount < 3) {

    $flip = rand(0, 1);
    $flipcount++;

    if($flip) {
        $headcount++;
        echo "H<br>";   
    }

    elseif ($headcount > 3) {

        $count_head = $headcount;
        for($i = 0; $i < $headcount; $i++) {
            $count_head = $i; 
        }}  

    else {
        $headcount = 0;
        echo "T<br>"; 
    }
}
echo "<p>It took {$flipcount} flips!</p>";
echo "<p>It took {$count_head} flips!</p>"; 
?>
```

Comment: What's your question? And please don't try to put highlighting in code blocks, it doesn't work.

Comment: The `for` loop is equivalent to `$count_head = $headcount - 1;` What are you trying to do there?

Comment: You'll never get into the `elseif ($headcount > 3)` block, because the `while` condition stops the loop when `$headcount >= 3`.

Comment: Thank you for ur response Mr.Barmar. I got total flips, that's fine. But how to count all the particular "H" counts. That means $count_head. if you remove the "for" loop and run the code, you will clearly know what I am asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use two variables that you increment when the roll is heads. One is the count of sequential heads, which gets set back to 0 when you roll tails, the other is the count of all heads, which doesn't get reset.

```
<?php 

$headcount = 0;
$allheads = 0;
$flipcount  = 0;

while ($headcount < 3) {

    $flip = rand(0, 1);
    $flipcount++;

    if($flip) {
        $headcount++;
        $allheads++;
        echo "H<br>";   
    }
    else {
        $headcount = 0;
        echo "T<br>"; 
    }
}
echo "<p>It took {$flipcount} flips!</p>";
echo "<p>There were {$allheads} heads!</p>"; 
?>
```

[DEMO](https://ideone.com/4UsrBy)

Comment: Mr.Barmar that was luminary. Iam Midun from India. Thank you for the help. Since I new here, I am very suspicious about my behavior here. This is big for me realy. I need to learn a lot from people like you.

Comment: I have a doubt. Why srand() function in the code. It is working fine without srand(). What its role in the code? Can you explain?

Comment: I needed that on ideone.com for some reason. I kept getting `TTT` without it.

Comment: But maybe it was just caching a result, not re-running the script.

Comment: What is the job of $headcount=0 in the else loop?

Comment: @MithunJack You're counting the number of heads in a row. So every time you roll tails, you have to reset the count to 0.

Comment: Thank you so much for clarification Mr Barmer. What should I do in order to strengthen this kind of math logic? Plz suggest any website or topics. Give me tips.

Comment: @MithunJack I have no idea what to suggest. To me, it's just common sense. Just think clearly about what you're doing.